# Worksheet change event with multiple selections

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that i keep a log of the changes that happen on it such as data entered into a cell or data deleted etc. This works great except for when multiple selections happen.

For example if i select B2 and D2 and F2 and deleted the contents of the cells the worksheet change event will only pick up the change for the first cell, B2. So i have no idea what happened to the other cells.

Is there a way i can get around this and either get it to log the worksheet change for the other cells or stop multiple selection deletes happening ?

Here is my code

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As 

Range)

Dim ws As Worksheet, iRow As Long, iCol As Long, Message As String, SheetId As String, iRowE As Long, iColE As Long, iRowB As Long, iColB As Long

Set ws = Sh
SheetId = Replace(ws.Name, " ", "")
SheetId = Left(SheetId, 2) & Right(SheetId, 2)

iRowB = Target.Row
iColB = Target.Column
iRowE = iRowB + Target.Rows.Count - 1
iColE = iColB + Target.Columns.Count - 1

Message = Format(Now(), "ddHHmmss") & Application.UserName & "-" & SheetId

For iRow = iRowB To iRowE
  For iCol = iColB To iColE
    Message = Message & "|" & Format(iRow, " 0") & Format(iCol, " 0") & "|" & CStr(ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Text)
  Next iCol
Next iRow

If Not FileExists("L:\HC\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & Format(Now(), "YYYYMM") & ".Log") Then
  Call LogIt("L:\HC\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & Format(Now(), "YYYYMM") & ".Log", "ddHHmmssUSER-sheet|row col|value|row col|value")
End If

Call LogIt("L:\HC\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & Format(Now(), "YYYYMM") & ".Log", Message)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than looping through the rows and columns as such, you can loop through each cell that was changed.  "Target" is a range and can be specified as more than 1 cell if that's what was changed in the process.

```
Dim objCell As Range

For Each objCell in Target
    ' Do Something
Next
```

I can see you've attempted to do something like that but using the cell approach should give you each individual address that has changed.

> Be careful though, mass amount of changes may cause some serious
>   performance issues for a single hit.

I hope that helps.

Comment: That would be the way to handle it, but imagine the user selecting the whole sheet...

Comment: @DarXyde Yep, hence my comment about mass changes.

Comment: The range that they can edit is only around 200 cells so even if they selected all of them it wouldnt be too terrible. I will try this and see if it works okay thankyou! Would i encase the code i have inside the For Each loop of the cells ?

Comment: @Skin So i tried the answer you suggested and the issue is that the worksheet change event doesnt fire more than once when multiple cells are selected. So even when you do it cell by cell it doesnt recognize that more than 1 was changed so you dont get the cell addresses.

Comment: That's correct, it's a single call but target contains all of the cells.  It won't fire for each individual cell, otherwise Excel would potentially have a meltdown.  If that's a problem then there's not much you can do given you can't change the way the standard event behaves.  Also, you said "multiple cells are selected", it doesn't matter what's selected, it matters what changed.  So if you DELETE all of the selected cells, TARGET will contain them all.

Comment: @Skin I see thankyou for that.I belive i have got it working now!

Comment: @GamerGypps perfect, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Some guidelines:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Range

    'Loop all selections
    For Each cell In Target

        With cell
            Debug.Print .Address
        End With

    Next cell

    'Exit sub when selection is more than one cell
    If Target.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```